# Is it possible to force the iPad screen to refresh on rotate?

Tags: javascript, ipad, dom-events, supersized

I have a page that uses supersized as a full screen background.  Depending on the size of the screen width, a different background image is displayed.  However, when I rotate my iPad from portrait to landscape (or vice versa) i.e. from a 768 to a 1024 pixel screen width the page needs to be refreshed before the alternative background can be displayed.

Is there any way I can force the iPad to refresh the page when the screen is rotated, perhaps using Javascript?

This is the supersized code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        
        jQuery(function($){
            var image_filename = 'GA.jpg';

            if($(window).width() < 1024) {
                image_filename = '_people.jpg';
            }
            $.supersized({
                slides  :   [ {image : 'images/'+image_filename, title : 'Image Credit: none'} ]
            });
        });
        
    </script>
```

Comment: You are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498934/detect-change-in-orientation-using-javascript