# 100dvh extends past bottom on Android Chrome fullscreen

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, fullscreen

I believe this is a bug, but wanted to confirm... I'm also looking for any workaround suggestions.

I have a html page - when I use the following css, a red border is correctly drawn around the full screen.

(works in desktop and mobile)

```css
html {
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  height: 100dvh;
}
```

However, when I [request fullscreen mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen) (android chrome), the page extends past the bottom, and the red border at the bottom is no longer visible. (Touching the screen, will cause the page to re-render, which fixes the issue).

Here is a minimal working reproduction (open in your android chrome) - https://jsbin.com/netiyud/8

Code is here: https://jsbin.com/netiyud/edit?html,css,js,console,output

- **Can anyone reproduce this?**
- **Is this a bug?**
- **Is there a fix/workaround?**

**Software:**

- Chrome Version: 116.0.5845.163
- OS: Android 13
- Device: Samsung S22 Ultra

**Related**

- [How do I get viewport height units to work in fullscreen mode in Chrome on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691878/how-do-i-get-viewport-height-units-to-work-in-fullscreen-mode-in-chrome-on-andro#comment135799259_42691878)

### Screenshots

I've added screenshots (which I think highlights the problem being caused by the "black camera space" at the top):

1. Screenshot before fullscreen
2. Screenshot immediately after fullscreen (see bottom overflows)
3. Screenshot after touching screen (fixes itself on interaction)

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry Nick, I have deleted my answer. I have modified it a few times trying different approaches but no-one worked. I tried both fullscreen and only to hide the address bar on mobile. The problem with the bottom border is always there. My advice is if possible to remove the border from the design, or just to ignore this minor problem.