# How to give different views for same url for different devices with same resolution?

Tags: html, asp.net, css

While referring to concept ‘Responsive Web Design’ and using it any ASP.NET project.
I found in Google Developers article as:

A CSS media query we recommend to use for smartphones is:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {...}
```

Now, iPad is having resolution of 1024x768 and Lumia 920 with resolution of 1280x768 similar to a PC screen resolution. How can I give different views in browser using media tag (i.e. one for PC and one for iPad and one for Lumia 920)?

I don’t want separate mobile URLs. I just want to have all in one just by making use of CSS. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to this, but if you choose to do it with CSS, you'll have to trust the screen-width to identify the devices, and that can be pretty limited.

Even so, CSS solution is simple, and you can do it this way

---

```
CSS solution
```

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14942185/3555591),

> The current best way that I use to detect a mobile device is to know
>   its width and use the corresponding media query to catch it

Suggesting you do this:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

[css-source](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

---

> Javascript solution

The other way to identify the device is using javascript. There is already a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser?lq=1) telling how that can be accomplished.

Comment: I have to an old(Pentium 4) PC, having max resolution as 1024x768. So according to this solution both(iPad and Desktop) will have same view?

Comment: Yup, it will fall under these conditions. That solution is CSS based, so it's very limited. You should consider using javascript if you want to identify the devices with precision.

Comment: ok so can you suggest any javascript reference/examples for similar case solution?

Comment: There is similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser?lq=1)