# CSS media queries for handheld and not small browser screens

Tags: css, media-queries

In the modern days of hi-resolution handhelds, is it possible to detect handheld with CSS media queries only and not by resolution? I don't want to target iPads only like some other questions here, I want to be sure if I'm using a handheld browser or a desktop browser so the user will see mobile CSS on hi-res tablets and will not see mobile layout if he resizes the browser window. Is that possible with CSS only?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942081/detect-if-a-browser-in-a-mobile-device-ios-android-phone-tablet-is-used

Answer (score 0):

You use it for example like this

```
@media handheld and (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ...  }
```

Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

To be noted, unfortunately many "handheld" still doesn't pick up that type so you will have to address those individually.

Further help: [Detect if a browser in a mobile device (iOS/Android phone/tablet) is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942081/detect-if-a-browser-in-a-mobile-device-ios-android-phone-tablet-is-used)

Comment: @C0dekid.php Yeah, I know ... updated with a note and posted as a wiki as there is a good answer already.

Comment: That's the problem that many handhelds, namely Apple stuff, don't support it because it "does not supply high-end web content" whatever that was supposed to mean.

Comment: @pokrishka Why do you need to know if it is handheld? .. I strongly recommend your work on a resolution based solution.

Comment: the UX team in the project has it as a requirement that a mobile touch oriented design is shown in any handheld/tabled, no matter how big it is and desktop design is shown on desktops even when you resize the screen (scrollbars introduced).

Comment: @pokrishka The is not one answer to your question, follow the links in my answer and their links and so on .. you will see that it is quite a challenge to address "mobile touch oriented" devices ... especially with media queries only (scripting will help vastly).