# How can I add a menu-icon on mobile devices only?

Tags: jquery

How can I add a menu-icon when I scale a page down below 769px?

I added a button a one page site that I am developing in order to display the  menu on mobile devices.

Used this in jquery:

```
if($(window).width() < 769){
    $('html').append('<i class="fa fa-bars menu-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
}
```

The menu shows up if initially start the site with a window of size below 769px..but if I load the page on a big screen and try to resize the window to a width below 769,the menu-icon does not show up immediately.Instead I have to refresh the page for it to appear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Wosley, Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery

Comment: CSS show/hide based on media query is much better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the script you run just runs once... on page load I guess. Why would it react on resizing the window? You dont specify that in your script.

Its far easier to just add the icon in the original html and display/ hide it with [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries):

```
.menu-icon { display: none; }

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-icon { display: block; }
}
```

Its also possible to [detect mobile devices via css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942081/detect-if-a-browser-in-a-mobile-device-ios-android-phone-tablet-is-used), not just based on the window width.

Comment: @Alex.I Preferred not to use display:none because it can be bad for SEO I assume, since it will still pick up as a  hidden content.Hope you can correct me there if am wrong.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico no, its just a hidden icon... its even better regarding seo reasons since google for instane recognizes your site is mobile friendly. it is absolutely best practice

Comment: @WosleyAlarico all the big frameworks, like bootstrap for example, do it like that :) thats what media queries are for!

Comment: Really appreciate the explanation.Thanks. then I'll  prefer that since it is simpler than having to use jquery.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico no problem, youre welcome. though, you should REALLY know that when doing websites...

Comment: @ Alex.That is actually what I normally do.Was just trying the js  because of te SEO concern that I just taught me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your code inside `$(window).resize()` like follows so that whenever page size gets modified; the handler will get invoked and you can run your logic accordingly:

```
$('html').append('<i class="fa fa-bars menu-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>'); //append the icon to html
$("i.fa-bars.menu-icon").hide(); //hide it initially

$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 769){
        $("i.fa-bars.menu-icon").show(); //show it on mobile view
    }
    else
    {
        $("i.fa-bars.menu-icon").hide(); //hide it on bigger screen
    }
}).trigger('resize');//firing the resize immediately
```

Comment: this would add an icon every time you resize the window beneath the specified width

Comment: now youre simulating css media queries with a width detection for every pixel resized. this is not performant and not necessary

Comment: @Alex - I agree...!

Comment: I tried that but the problem is that it will only add when you resize the page.If I open the page immediately on mobile view,the button will never show up because because one can never resize on mobile.
And also,in your answer you used the .hide() function.Would that not be bad for SEO?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @WosleyAlarico - updated the code bit to deal with the issue you were facing on mobile device. I really can't judge about your SEO concern...!

Comment: Well I can still vote for the answer too since I learned from it too.By the way I'll research more about how to use the trigger function since am still  a beginner in js and don't know how to  play with such yet.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico - sure. Thanks...!