# CSS Media queries and device resolution

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsive

I am fresh new to CSS in general and responsive design specially,
I had an old website which i successfully redesigned with CSS and everything is fine, when trying to make it responsive i just discovered media queries and i started with restyling the footer using :

```
@media screen and (max-width:720px){ etc ...}
```

That works ok and my footer is restyling well, my question is :
This looks fine in my mobile which is 720px width, but in the case of a mobile with for example 1080px width it will show the desktop version ? how to avoid that ?
I mean if i try with :

```
@media screen and (max-width:1280px){ etc ...}
```

To include high resolution mobiles, it will show the mobile version on desktop screen that are 1280px width ?
What is the correct usage, ? Thanks

Comment: There is a difference between device pixels (akin to resolution) and CSS pixels. So a high res device like a retina one can use 4 actual physical pixels to correspond to one CSS pixel. On the whole you don't worry about device resolution, just CSS pixels which is what media queries will pick up.

Comment: visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942081/detect-if-a-browser-in-a-mobile-device-ios-android-phone-tablet-is-used hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Don’t worry about a device being mobile or desktop or whatever.

Media queries allow you to apply difference style sheets based on the window size.

If you have a media query for devices that are 720px wide or less and the design in that CSS works for screens that wide and *another* media query for devices that are wider that that, and the design works for devices that size, then everything is fine.

Comment: I just tried in my device, for max-width 720px it is ok but if i rotate to landscape it show the desktop version because my phone width at landscape is 1520px, how to avoid this ? Thanks for your answer