# Remove Hamburger Menu from Community Site when on Mobile

Tags: css, mobile, salesforce, salesforce-communities

I need to remove the hamburger menu when a user is viewing the community site on a mobile device. I'm told I can do this via CSS, but I'm not sure how. Any ideas?

Doesn't seem like there are any declarative options out there. I found information pertaining to Mobile Publisher, but that doesn't apply.

Thanks!

Comment: media queries and css (display: none)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect if a browser in a mobile device (iOS/Android phone/tablet) is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942081/detect-if-a-browser-in-a-mobile-device-ios-android-phone-tablet-is-used)

Comment: Can you share the CSS you have, so that we can see what's going wrong with the media query in the below answer?

Comment: First: 

'@media screen and (max-width: 776px){
  .hamburger-menu{
    display: none;
  }
}'


Second:


'!important @media screen and (max-width: 776px){ .hamburger-menu{ display: none !important; } }'


The first one did nothing and gives no errors. The second one gave an error (red circle x) of "Unexpected token '!important' at line 7, col 1. I removed the ! at the beginning and now the error is Expected LBRACE at line 7, col 11.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 776px){
  .hamburger-menu{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I saved this and published the site and the hamburger menu is still there. I updated the max width to 600 to see if maybe my screen is too large and it still didn't disappear.

Comment: try to put !important 
@media screen and (max-width: 776px){
  .hamburger-menu{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
Also please check the meta for responsive is there in the document.

If it is not working please share more information.

Comment: Pasting that gave an error (red circle x) of "Unexpected token '!important' at line 7, col 1. I removed the ! at the beginning and now the error is Expected LBRACE at line 7, col 11.