# How to detect landscape mobile-only on ios?

Tags: css, ios, landscape

This works to detect landscape on a mobile phone on **Android**:

@media (first_media_query) or ((orientation: landscape) and (pointer: coarse))

> first_media_query = any media query

However, it doesn't work for ios (tested on iPhone and iPad).

How do I fix the code above? (it must work on both android and iOS)

If possible, I prefer to avoid [min/max- device-width](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) and use device features detection instead.

`(orientation: landscape)` combined with `aspect-ratio` or `-wekbit-pixel-ratio` seems a good candidate, however I am looking for a solution that **relies on device features**

Comment: hmm. maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50302305/4935162)? nest the landscape media query inside

Comment: We cannot detect the device type on the CSS side in a healthy way. The healthiest method would be to detect it with javascript and define a class or attribute to the body.

Comment: @Yarin_007 referenced answer seems to work in fact. It was the way I used it that it was wrong (I posted an answer, and will update the question to reflect the issue better, as it was a different issue than iOS).

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue:

**Original code** (works on android but not ios):

```
 @media (first_media_query) or (second_media_query)
```

> second_media_query = (orientation: landscape) and (pointer: coarse)

**Cross-platform code** (works on both ios and android - without **or**):

```
 @media (first_media_query), (second_media_query)
```