# Wordpress Detect User Phone Type

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there any way to detect user phone type for wordpress??

I found some plugin but I would like to write the script myself.

Here is my situation. 
I need to change the web meta name viewport to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, minimal-ui">
```

when detect user is using iphone4 while load

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

during normal browsing.

Earlier, I found a method in wordpress to detect whether user is in mobile or not. 
But is there any method to detect the user phone type?

Comment: maybe a javascript will do see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803838/detecting-if-a-device-is-able-to-change-orientation-in-javascript/13805337#13805337

Comment: Check the `HTTP User Agent`. Its not an WordPress Question!

Comment: @AdrianPreuss Can you explain how this is a PHP question? He doesn't even mention that he's *using* PHP, let alone asking anything about it.

Comment: @Adi Inbar, he can use many options to realize that. either with Javascript over `window.navigator.userAgent` otherwise with PHP `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`