# menu links not floating to right

Tags: html, css

I am making a custom responsive menu. And have two links **logout and website front** on my menu which I need to float right. When in desktop mode to the other side. I have tried float right but can not get them both aligned.

When mobile view i need the floated right links to just be normal vertical.

You can view it here example: http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/GgLjmL and http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/full/GgLjmL/

What would be the best way.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-menu">
<a class="toggleMenu" href="#">Menu</a>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Catalog</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Categories</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Categories</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Extensions</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Modules</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sales</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="top">Customers</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Customer Group</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">System</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Setting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="top">Design</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Layouts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Banners</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="top">Users</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">User</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">User Group</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Website Front</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="alert alert-danger">Test</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, 
#menu, 
ul, 
li, 
a  {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container-menu {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

.toggleMenu {
    display:  none;
    background: #666;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
}
#menu {
    list-style: none;
    *zoom: 1;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    background: rgba(19,19,19,1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,19,19,1) 0%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 0%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 2%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 4%, rgba(61,61,61,1) 27%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(19,19,19,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(17,17,17,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(102,102,102,1)), color-stop(0%, rgba(43,43,43,1)), color-stop(2%, rgba(44,44,44,1)), color-stop(4%, rgba(71,71,71,1)), color-stop(27%, rgba(61,61,61,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(28,28,28,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,19,19,1) 0%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 0%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 2%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 4%, rgba(61,61,61,1) 27%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,19,19,1) 0%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 0%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 2%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 4%, rgba(61,61,61,1) 27%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,19,19,1) 0%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 0%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 2%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 4%, rgba(61,61,61,1) 27%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(19,19,19,1) 0%, rgba(17,17,17,1) 0%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 0%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 0%, rgba(44,44,44,1) 2%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 4%, rgba(61,61,61,1) 27%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#131313', endColorstr='#1c1c1c', GradientType=0 );
}

#menu:before,
#menu:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}

#menu:after {
    clear: both;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#menu a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none
}

#menu li {
    position: relative;
}

#menu > li {
    float: left;
}

#menu > li > a {
    display: block;
}

#menu li  ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

#menu > li.hover > ul {
    left: 0;
}
#menu li li.hover ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

#menu ul .top {
    background-image: url('./images/arrow-right.png'); 
    background-position: 95% center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

#menu li li a {
    display: block;
    background: black; /* A grey background */
    opacity: 0.7; /* 80% opacity */
    position: relative;
    z-index:100;
    width: 147px;
}

#menu li li li a {
    background: black; /* A grey background */
    opacity: 0.7; /* 80% opacity */

    z-index:200;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .active {
        display: block;
    }
    #menu > li {
        float: none;
    }

    #menu li li a {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #menu ul {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #menu > li.hover > ul , #menu li li.hover ul {
        position: static;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

HTML

```
  <li class='float-right'><a href="">Website Front</a></li>
    <li class='float-right'><a href="">Logout</a></li>
```

CSS

```
.float-right{
   float:right!important;
}
```

Example: **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyraQX**

Comment: In mobile view it still shows to the right is it possible to get them vertical and to the left in mobile view?

Comment: You cannot do that will simple css. You can use some javascript to detect if mobile and then remove this class: `$(".float-right").removeClass("float-right")`. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13805337/2063910

Answer (score 0):

if count of your menu is fixed you can select it by `nth-of-type` and add float: right;

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEwaMJ

here is code. but if you don't know count of menu elements then add special classes and select by classes