# Responsive Design on iPad Works but Only Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Here is the entire, relevant code sample: http://pastebin.com/b7P5Hjt1

(See comments below this post for links to screenshots; SO only lets me have two links)

Then, all landscape orientations are zoomed/scaled improperly after the first turn. I cannot for the life of me figure out what is the problem. I think it could be the percent calculations happening before the orientation is fully adjusted, but I don't know how to test that, much less fix it.

I found out about the onOrientationChange function here on StackOverflow, and was linked to the Apple documentation on it. However, that was over a week ago and I only have the code from the post, not the URL. I have searched for it to link to again, but I could not find it.

Any help, questions, or clarifications are appreciated!

Comment: Initial page load: http://s9.postimage.org/5hffconfj/IMG_0001.jpg

90 degree turn once: http://s9.postimage.org/dlnjhf9un/IMG_0002_2.jpg

Turn back to initial orientation: http://s9.postimage.org/9b8vlu4rj/IMG_0003_2.jpg

90 degree turn again: http://s9.postimage.org/4y5qpo6n3/IMG_0004_2.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I did the following:

Changed

> initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no

to

> user-scalable=no

Apparently, the initial scale, coupled with the user-scalable, doesn't allow it to resize. I then added the following to the end of my updateOrientation function:

> $(".container").css('width', $(window).width()+'px');

I don't know if BOTH are needed, but both worked. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:  You need to bind the updateOrientation function to the window's orientation change event, rather than the document's body.

On line 201 you set the onorientationchange event to trigger your updateOrientation function.  Instead, you should bind the window's orientation change to your function.

```
window.onorientationchange = function() { updateOrientation(); }
```

An example is available here:
[How do I correctly detect orientation change using javascript and Phonegap in IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284878/how-do-i-correctly-detect-orientation-change-using-javascript-and-phonegap-in-io)

Comment: I made that change, and I am ttill ending up with a miss-scaled orientation. I took the body binding out, and updated it to add the window.onorientationchange = function() { updateOrientation(); } code you supplied, after reading through the post you linked to. Any help? Would it help to have a new Pastebin?