# Force portrait orientation on iPhone with phonegap

Tags: android, iphone, ios, cordova

I want portrait orientation for my application, I tryed with:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity ... android:screenOrientation="portrait" ... android:configChanges="orientation| ..." />
```

and
config.xml:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

That works perfectly on my android phone, but not on iPhone 4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Open **'ProjectName'-info.plist** file in Xcode.

In 'Supported interface orientations' array, keep support for Portrait mode only.

Like this-

[image]

then your phonegap app will run only in Portait Mode on iPhone.

Comment: I'm programming on windows :( I don't have a mac computer. But maybe i will borrow some for do that. Thanks anyway, think that is the only solution.

Comment: though you have Windows machine, You can still modify plist file, it is xml format file

Comment: I havnt't any .plist file on my project :S

Comment: The plist files will not even be generated on windows because PhoneGap doesn't have the libraries to create xcode projects.. Thats why this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For iphone, you have to developp with xcode. Just create a new phonegap project and on xcode clic on your project, go in Summary and just select the orientation you want to support
[image: portrait in xcode]

And that all you have to do

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if you want to use **only javascript and PhoneGap** to do this, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284878/how-do-i-correctly-detect-orientation-change-using-javascript-and-phonegap-in-io) link would be helpful. If you're using Xcode then you can go to supported device orientations and choose the desired orientation and then use `shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation` method to set the desired orientation.  You might also want to look into [this](https://github.com/acti0nm4n/Phonegap-Orientation-iOS).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using only javascript and I dont want to detect when i change the orientationt. I want to disable the landscape view. But thanks I think that I'll have to remake the code for adapt the content to landscape.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the first line in the latest phonegap worked for me.

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Of course that's not going to help with your iPhone problem but it does mean that your next Android app will be a few bytes smaller…