# Is there any Map event fired when map is loaded completely when we device is oriented from portrait to landscape mode?

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

We are using ESRI ArcGIS JavaScript API in one of our Mobile web app. When map is loaded first time, Onload event is fired. But when we change orientation from Portrait to Landscape, OnLoad event does not fired. We need such event so that when map is completely loaded in Landscape mode we can perform some opearion. We know that there is Orientation change event in javascript but we need event which should fire when Map is loaded completely in Landscape mode after orientation change event is fired?

Answer (score 0):

This StackOverflow post might already answer your question:

[How do I correctly detect orientation change using javascript and Phonegap in IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284878/how-do-i-correctly-detect-orientation-change-using-javascript-and-phonegap-in-io)

There is also this blog post:

http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2011/12/06/429/

Basically:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', handleOrientation, false);

function handleOrientation() {
    if (orientation == 0) {
        //portraitMode, do your stuff here
    }
    else if (orientation == 90) {
        //landscapeMode
    }
    else if (orientation == -90) {
        //landscapeMode
    }
    else if (orientation == 180) {
        //portraitMode
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

Comment: This is does not solve my problem since I want Event which will fire when Map is completely loaded in Landscape mode.

Comment: You will still need an even listener for the orientationchange event, but from the blog post I linked to mobile browsers declare a global variable called `orientation`. On page load, you might try looking at the `window.orientation` property and calling `handleOrientation` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need a combination of two events:

1. The javascript `orientationchange` event, and
2. The ArcGIS API map's `update-end` event.

In the handler for the `orientationchange` event, set a flag variable to indicate that you're waiting for the end of an update. The handler for `update-end` checks the flag to see if you've just changed orientation, does whatever magic you're trying to do, then unsets the flag.