# The <select> tag with options has wrong position after software keyboard being closed on mobile Safari

Tags: ios, select, keyboard

I'm using `select` tag with options to show search results in the mobile Safari.

**The problem is next:**

1. user sets focus to the input `onblur="ShowSelectTag()" type="text"`
   after that keyboard appeared
2. user writes some text to search by and pushes the button
3. "blur" event takes place and the select element with results is showed in a proper place
4. the keyboard is hidden (because of blur event) but the position of the select element remains the same.

**The HTML is as follows:**

```
<input type="text" onblur="ShowSelectTag()" />
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="return false;" />
<select id="SelectToShow" style="width:0px;">
    <option>otpion</option>
    <option>otpion</option>
    <option>otpion</option>
    <option>otpion</option>
    <option>otpion</option>       
</select>
```

**The JS method to show `select` tag:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowSelectTag()
    {
        var Select = document.getElementById("SelectToShow");
        var event;
        event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
        Select.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
</script>
```

Link to the image is next: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B2873888E0BA0E45!1335&authkey=!ADjrvx4jm1rCDWg&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Link to the html file: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B2873888E0BA0E45%211334

If someone have experience with that, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, @rahul_send89. It's good solution in case your page does not has scrolling. If it does, after you've scrolled the page, the select tag would be positioned at the same coordinates as before.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="searchText" onblur="ShowSelectTag()" />
<input type="button" value="click me" onclick="return false;" />
<select id="SelectToShow" style="width:0px;position:absolute;">
        <option>otpion</option>
        <option>otpion</option>
        <option>otpion</option>
        <option>otpion</option>
        <option>otpion</option>        
    </select>

<script>
   function getPos(el) {
    for (var lx=0, ly=0;
         el != null;
         lx += el.offsetLeft, ly += el.offsetTop, el = el.offsetParent);
    return {x: lx,y: ly};
   }
   (function () {
      var myInput = document.getElementById('searchText');
      var pos = getPos(myInput);
      document.getElementById("SelectToShow").style.left = pos.x+"px";
      document.getElementById("SelectToShow").style.top = pos.y+"px";
   })();

   function ShowSelectTag()
    {
        var Select = document.getElementById("SelectToShow");
        var event;
        event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
        Select.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
</script>
```

let me know if it helped  !

Comment: Doesn't fix it. Checkout http://jsbin.com/deraxatagewi/1 in an iPad. It still shows the select above the input after keyboard opened and closed instead of below.

Comment: sadly, it still doesnt work. What I mean is the dropdown list shows above the input, instead of below. It's not about the initial position calculation but rather of how iOS calculates where it thinks it has enough space to show the list.

Comment: @TomRoggero : only working for iPhone . not iPad . ?
you can always modify the position and add a width constant m sure it will work .

Comment: @TomRoggero: or use a setTimeout for iPad . using iPad specific code .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript

Comment: As commented on the answer below, apple just doesn't allow you to do so.

Comment: @TomRoggero : if your are building a web app its fine . if you are building a hybrid app u still have option to call a native function setNeedDisplay .. u can make keyboard-plugin or make your own selection . don't need to use apple selection at all...

Comment: @TomRoggero : u can still make a custom pop up . which look similar to iPad select and make a layout change your self . iOS webkit orientation change call a autolayout & setNeedDisplay for the page  .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284878/how-do-i-correctly-detect-orientation-change-using-javascript-and-phonegap-in-io .. make a custom popover select . https://github.com/sparkbox/Custom-Selectbox . don't use inbuilt .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a timeout to let the keyboard close **before** you open the SELECT:

```
onblur="window.setTimeout('ShowSelectTag()',1000);"
```

Then try reducing the delay to 0 to see it it works instantly.

```
onblur="window.setTimeout('ShowSelectTag()',0);"
```

Comment: Asynchronicity added to either .focus() or window.open() equivalents won't trigger anything on iOS, as they require direct user action, and async'ing it makes it indirect.

Comment: Thank you, @FrancescoMM, I tried that solution. It does not help, Tom Roggero is right about how an iOS handle events.