# How to detect device orientation with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jqtouch

I've seen a number of ways to detect the screen orientation of the device, including using a check to test innerWidth versus innerHeight, like so.

```
function getOrientation(){
    var orientation = window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight ? "Landscape" : "Primary";
    return orientation;
}
```

But what if I want to check for *changes* in screen orientation as well with an event listener? I've tried this code but it doesn't work for me.

```
  function doOnOrientationChange()
  {
    switch(window.orientation) 
    {  
      case -90:
      case 90:
        alert('landscape');
        break; 
      default:
        alert('portrait');
        break; 
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', doOnOrientationChange);

  // Initial execution if needed
  doOnOrientationChange();
```

It doesn't detect device orientation, and the listener does not register for me (I'm using Chrome's device emulator).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

First, as per the [Screen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation) documentation, using >= Chrome 38, Firefox, and IE 11, the screen object is available to not only view the orientation, but to also register the listener on each time the device orientation changes.

`screen.orientation.type` will explicitly let you know what the orientation is, and for the listener you can use something simple like:

```
screen.orientation.onchange = function (){
    // logs 'portrait' or 'landscape'
    console.log(screen.orientation.type.match(/\w+/)[0]);
};
```

Second, for compatibility with other browsers like Safari that aren't compatible with Screen, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284878/how-do-i-correctly-detect-orientation-change-using-javascript-and-phonegap-in-io) shows that you can continue to use innerWidth and innerHeight on window resizing.

```
 function getOrientation(){
    var orientation = window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight ? "Landscape" : "Portrait";
    return orientation;
}

 window.onresize = function(){ getOrientation(); }
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution only works for Chrome >= 39 and Firefox Mobile on smartphones. The OP added the tag "ios" and the Screen API is not the solution for that.