# Detect if a device supports being rotated

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, is it possible to detect whether or not a device has *the ability* to be rotated?

Note: I am *not* asking how to get the current orientation of the device.

Context: I have to show a "rotate your device" warning if a device is in landscape orientation. But since that is only relevant on devices that can actually be rotated to portrait (usually phones and tablets, but not laptops and desktops), I want to determine if the device can be rotated first. Currently, I check if the device is a mobile device using sniffer.js. But I am curious if there is a better way?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917664/detect-viewport-orientation-if-orientation-is-portrait-display-alert-message-ad) looks like a good place to start, as does [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650949/how-to-detect-device-orientation-with-javascript).  I'm not sure if the Screen API has a way to detect if it *can* be rotated.  Though, taking a step back, is this really the correct approach to the underlying problem?  What is that underlying problem that is solved by rotating the screen, and only solved on mobile devices?

Comment: https://whatwebcando.today/device-position.html