# Detect screen orientation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, window, orientation, screen-orientation

I need to detect the change between the orientation of a device at runtime:
trying to use the Screen Api (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation) on an Angular project I am receiving an error: `Property 'orientation' does not exist on type 'Screen'`.
**Orientation is not present in the Screen interface!**

*That some solutions that I was trying to replicate, without having success:*
 - [How do I correctly detect orientation change using javascript and Phonegap in IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284878/how-do-i-correctly-detect-orientation-change-using-javascript-and-phonegap-in-io)

How could I achieve it in a cross-browser friendly way?

**Scenario:**

```
count = 0;
countState() {
  (window.screen.orientation.type === 'landscape-primary' || window.screen.orientation.type === 'landscape-secondary') ? count++ : count--;
}
<button (click)="countState()">Count</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `orientation` read-only property of the [Screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation) interface returns the current orientation of the screen.

#### Syntax

```
var orientation = window.screen.orientation;
```

#### Example

```
var orientation = (screen.orientation || {}).type || screen.mozOrientation || screen.msOrientation;

if (orientation === "landscape-primary") {
  console.log("That looks good.");
} else if (orientation === "landscape-secondary") {
  console.log("Mmmh... the screen is upside down!");
} else if (orientation === "portrait-secondary" || orientation === "portrait-primary") {
  console.log("Mmmh... you should rotate your device to landscape");
} else if (orientation === undefined) {
  console.log("The orientation API isn't supported in this browser :(");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a possible, simple solution would be something like this:

```
function getOrientation() {
  if (window.outerWidth > window.outerHeight) {
    return 'landscape';
  return 'portrait';
}
```

Comment: I just added on the question a **Scenario** to help you understand better what could I need.
Pierre replied here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4917796/6916104):
`On many devices, when the keyboard is shown, the availableWidth will be greater than the height, incorrectly giving landscape orientation. `
Not really sure that this solution looks to fit my needs.