# How to detect orientationchange or resize event in iframe context by amp-ad?

Tags: javascript, amp-html

In amp-ad iframe context, I can not capture `orientationchange` or `resize` event.

```
// Don't work because `window` object in iframe context.
window.addEventListener("resize", function() { console.info("resize") });
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function { console.info("orientationchange") } );
```

Is there a way to detect `orientationchange` or `resize` event?

Comment: Have you seen this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284878/how-do-i-correctly-detect-orientation-change-using-phonegap-on-ios