# JS window.matchMedia right syntax

Tags: javascript, matchmedia

I have a problem of how to write a correct sentence reflecting full css @media query with screen size **and** screen orientation (example bellow) with JS `window.matchMedia`, all I can find is a separate example for size (without orientation) and orientation (without size). What is the right syntax of this CSS example:

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 483px) and (orientation: landscape) {}
```

in this code:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {
   // how to add a screen size to this exact code?
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is the same as the CSS. That's the point of it.

```
window.matchMedia("only screen and (min-width: 483px) and (orientation: landscape)").matches
```

Comment: Does it have to have "only screen and"?, I did't sow this "part" in any documentations or examples @Quentin

Comment: And little follow up here, how do I add an `eventListner` for changing screen **orientation**? (I'm new to JS, so I need a little bit of help)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284878/how-do-i-correctly-detect-orientation-change-using-phonegap-on-ios