# componentDidUpdate not working in safari browser while navigating from portrait to landscape

Tags: reactjs

`componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method is not called while navigating from portrait to landscape in iPhone 6 safari browser. Could anyone please let me know whether there any workaround for this?

Comment: please provide some code so we can better understand

Comment: You have to somehow detect the orientation with an event, then save it in your local state or redux store. componentDidUpdate will only be call if a prop or your state changes

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` is called when component's state or props changes. Unless you do track orientation mode in your device and pass it to your component, there will be no lifecycle update.

Comment: But  I see in chrome iphone simulator, the componentDidUpdate is called while navigating from portrait to landscape even though im not updating any of the props.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but that should work

```
constructor() {

  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', this.onOrientationChange);

  this.state = {
    orientation: null
  }

}

onOrientationChange = () => {
    switch(window.orientation) {  
      case -90 || 90:
        this.setState({orientation: 'landscape'})
        break; 
      default:
      this.setState({orientation: 'portrait'})
        break; 
    }
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  console.log('componentDidUpdate called', this.state.orientation)
}
```

Take a look at that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284878/how-do-i-correctly-detect-orientation-change-using-phonegap-on-ios)