# How to detect screen orientation in mobile website when using react js and orientationchange event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I want to detect screen orientation changes using the event `orientationchange`, which is [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event) by all major mobile browsers.

I add the event listener in `componentDidMount` and set the state from inside the event callback.

However, I see that when the event first fires as a result of change from portrait to landscape the state is not updated to landscape. Then when I change the orientation from landscape back to portrait, the state says the orientation is landscape. After this each time I change the orientation the state always says the opposite of the actual orientation. I'm not sure if I should be using some lifecycle react method or my detection is not good.

I tested the code using Chrome developer tools `Toggle device toolbar`.
This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

class AppInfo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    screenOrientation: 'portrait'
  }

  isPortraitMode = () => {
    console.log(this.state);
    const { screenOrientation } = this.state;
    return screenOrientation === 'portrait';
  }

  setScreenOrientation = () => {
    if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {
      console.log('orientation: portrait');
      this.setState({
        screenOrientation: 'portrait'
      });
    }

    if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {
      console.log('orientation: landscape');
      this.setState({
        screenOrientation: 'landscape'
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', this.setScreenOrientation);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(`orientation: from render: isPortraitMode = ${this.isPortraitMode()}`);
    <div>
      Hello
    </div>
  }
}

export default AppInfo;
```

Comment: You might wanna see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36087703/1263904

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559463/9444013

Answer (score 5):

Here is an implementation using hooks for react that tracks screen orientation using a custom hook from [GitHub](https://github.com/bence-toth/react-hook-screen-orientation/blob/master/src/index.js) for obtaining and tracking orientation. It creates the event listener every time the component is mounted using useEffect and it shuts off the listener everytime the component is dismounted:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const getOrientation = () =>
  window.screen.orientation.type

const useScreenOrientation = () => {
  const [orientation, setOrientation] =
    useState(getOrientation())

  const updateOrientation = event => {
    setOrientation(getOrientation())
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(
      'orientationchange',
      updateOrientation
    )
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener(
        'orientationchange',
        updateOrientation
      )
    }
  }, [])

  return orientation
}

export default useScreenOrientation
```

In my Android mobile the two values for orientation are: 'portrait-primary' and 'landscape-secondary'. In my Ubuntu system it is: 'landscape-primary'. In my Windows 10 Surface Book 2 laptop mode: 'protrait-primary'. Doesn't handle the switch to tablet well. And it doesn't detect the orientation change at all.
All this is under Chrome v 99.0.4844.84 (official build) (64 bit). The Mac OS Monterey v 12.2.1 reports 'landscape-primary' same version of Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information from your tests

Comment: this works! on this page you can find all possible values returned: https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/#dom-screen-orientation

Answer (score 2):

You could try triggering it with the "resize" event instead, as some devices don't provided the orientationchange event, but do fire the window's resize event.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", this.setScreenOrientation);
```

Answer (score 2):

orientationchange has been deprecated and it might or might not work in some browsers. Best bet now is to use one of the following options:

```
window.screen.orientation.addEventListener('change', function(e) { ... })
window.screen.orientation.onchange = function(e) { ... }
```

This way you can put whatever logic you want in the callback part of the listener, react or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your program works just fine, you just need to log it like this:

```
this.setState({screenOrientation: 'landscape'}, console.log('orientation: landscape'))
```

The reason behind it is that call to setState isn't synchronous but setState(updater, callback) is an async function and it takes the callback as second argument.