# React Native, Detect screen rotation change using portrait mode

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am using portrait mode in react-native application. But I want to capture the rotation event of the screen.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks...

Comment: Welcome Sinan! Have you tried https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation ?

Answer (score 18):

this function might help you
create a `useOrientation.js` file

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

export function useOrientation(){
  const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState("PORTRAIT");

  useEffect(() => {
    Dimensions.addEventListener('change', ({window:{width,height}})=>{
      if (width<height) {
        setOrientation("PORTRAIT")
      } else {
        setOrientation("LANDSCAPE")
    
      }
    })

  }, []);

  return orientation;
}
```

Comment: Use `Dimensions.removeEventListener` to remove the listener function in the `useEffect`.  It could lead to memory issues https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions

Comment: `Dimensions.removeEventListener` is now deprecated. Use the `remove()` method on the event subscription returned by `addEventListener()`.

Answer (score 11):

To complete the previous answers,
if you simply want your app to be responsive, it is easier to use `useWindowDimensions()`
https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions
Just put something like this in your root component :

```
const SCREEN_WIDTH = useWindowDimensions().width;
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = useWindowDimensions().height;
return (
        <View style={{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH, minHeight: SCREEN_HEIGHT}} >
            //the rest of your app
        </View>
    );
```

Comment: thank u, i use it with the prev answer, instead of using `addEventListener` in `useEffect` i add the conditions `if (width<height)` and add the width and height to `useEffect` depends arr, Its work well, do u have any other thoughts?

Comment: Calling the hook twice is waste, you can destructure instead `const { width, height } =...`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. If I rotate the phone the app stays in portrait mode (which is what I want) but the height & width reported remain the same where I would expect them to swap places.
Question is how to detect screen rotation for an app that's set to stay in portrait mode??

Answer (score 5):

With **useWindowDimensions**

```
import {useWindowDimensions} from "react-native"
export function useIsLandscape() {
  const {height, width} = useWindowDimensions()
  return width > height
}
```

A quick and easy native hook implementation, for 2022.

Comment: just adding useWindowDimensions() to the top solved my problem actually, it forced the state detection and therefore the whole app rerendering

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have several options. You can use the Dimensions API
https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions

You can add a listener for Dimensions.change and you could do something like

```
function isPortrait() {
  const dim = Dimension.get("screen")
  return dim.height >= dim.width
}

function isLandscape() {
  const dim = Dimension.get("screen")
  return dim.width >= dim.height
}
```

now add listen to dimension chagnes with

```
Dimensions.addEventListener("change", () => {
// orientation has changed, check if it is portrait or landscape here
})
```

Another posibility is to use the one of the orientation packages available such as https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker

Comment: Thanks for answer. But "Dimensions.addEventListener" not working. My app only works in portrait mode. So, when I flip the screen it doesn't go into "landSpace" mode and I don't want to use "landSpace" mode

Comment: on iOS you need to allow your app to rotate. In XCode you need to go to target and then in the Deployment Info -> Device Orientation enable the orientaitons your app should support. 
For android you'll have to modify your AndroidManifest file and set the screenOrientation on the activity tag. More info here: https://medium.com/building-with-react-native/how-to-lock-device-orientation-for-react-native-apps-android-ios-2x02-952c42cb51b1

Comment: But if I'm required to allow the app to rotate then how do I prevent the app from rendering itself in landscape mode? I want to stay in portrait mode but still detect if the user rotates the phone 90-degrees.

Answer (score 3):

**useDeviceOrientation**: will return an object which will be updated each time the device will change the orientation "true or false"

```
import { useDeviceOrientation } from "@react-native-community/hooks";
```

Example object returned by `useDeviceOrientation`:

```
{
  "landscape": false,
  "portrait": true,
}
```

We can destructure the object:

```
const { landscape } = useDeviceOrientation();
```

Than we can use it :

```
height: landscape ? "100%" : "30%"
```

Comment: There's an issue with this, I've found that if the device is in landscape when the hook starts, it returns {portrait: true, landscape: false} see https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks/issues/210

Answer (score 1):

Using React Native 0.73 I just add a [listener](https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions) in `useEffect()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = Dimensions.addEventListener('change', ({window, screen}) => {
      // code that runs when the orientation changes
    },
  );
  return () => subscription?.remove();
});
```

Comment: Great answer! Very clean