# How to detect screen orientation change in react-native app with a funtion component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm making a calculator App for react-native and I want to render different layout for buttons in landscape and portrait mode, how can I do it in a function component

my return:

```
return (
          <View style={styles.container}>

              <View style={styles.resultContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.resultText}>
                        {displayValue}
                    </Text>
              </View>

              <View style={styles.inputContainer } >
                  {renderButtons()}

              </View>

          </View>

             );
```

and my RenderButtons funtion

```
renderButtons = () =>{

        height = Dimensions.get('window').height
        width = Dimensions.get('window').width

      if(height > width){

        let layouts = buttons.map((buttonRows,index)=>{
            let rowItem = buttonRows.map((buttonItems,buttonIndex)=>{
                return <InputButton
                value={buttonItems}
                handleOnPress={handleInput.bind(buttonItems)}
                key={'btn-'+ buttonIndex}/>
            });
            return <View style={styles.inputRow} key={'row-' + index}>{rowItem}</View>
        });

        return layouts
      }
      else 
      {
        let layouts = buttons_landscape.map((buttonRows,index)=>{
          let rowItem = buttonRows.map((buttonItems,buttonIndex)=>{
              return <InputButton
              value={buttonItems}
              handleOnPress={handleInput.bind(buttonItems)}
              key={'btn-'+ buttonIndex}/>
          });
          return <View style={styles.inputRow} key={'row-' + index}>{rowItem}</View>
      });

      return layouts

      }
    }
```

of course (height > width) condition doesn't work because apparently the values are undefined, I'm kinda new to JS so please don't be to harsh on me for not knowing the obvious

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native, Detect screen rotation change using portrait mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62472029/react-native-detect-screen-rotation-change-using-portrait-mode)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-orientation-locker](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker)

```
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';


  _onOrientationDidChange = (orientation) => {
    if (orientation == 'LANDSCAPE-LEFT') {
      //do something with landscape left layout
    } else {
      //do something with portrait layout
    }
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    //The getOrientation method is async. It happens sometimes that
    //you need the orientation at the moment the js starts running on device.
    //getInitialOrientation returns directly because its a constant set at the
    //beginning of the js code.
    var initial = Orientation.getInitialOrientation();
    if (initial === 'PORTRAIT') {
      //do stuff
    } else {
      //do other stuff
    }
  },

  componentDidMount() {

    Orientation.getAutoRotateState((rotationLock) => this.setState({rotationLock}));
    //this allows to check if the system autolock is enabled or not.

    Orientation.lockToPortrait(); //this will lock the view to Portrait
    //Orientation.lockToLandscapeLeft(); //this will lock the view to Landscape
    //Orientation.unlockAllOrientations(); //this will unlock the view to all Orientations

    //get current UI orientation
    /*
    Orientation.getOrientation((orientation)=> {
      console.log("Current UI Orientation: ", orientation);
    });

    //get current device orientation
    Orientation.getDeviceOrientation((deviceOrientation)=> {
      console.log("Current Device Orientation: ", deviceOrientation);
    });
    */

    Orientation.addOrientationListener(this._onOrientationDidChange);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    Orientation.removeOrientationListener(this._onOrientationDidChange);
  }
```

Another approach can be [Here](https://newbedev.com/react-native-different-styles-applied-on-orientation-change)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library  [react-native-orientation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation)

**Example:**

```
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation';

 const AppScreen = () => {
  // ...

  const [deviceOrientation, setDeviceOrientation] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // The getOrientation method is async. It happens sometimes that
    // you need the orientation at the moment the JS runtime starts running on device.
    // `getInitialOrientation` returns directly because its a constant set at the
    // beginning of the JS runtime.

    // this locks the view to Portrait Mode
    Orientation.lockToPortrait();

    // this locks the view to Landscape Mode
    // Orientation.lockToLandscape();

    // this unlocks any previous locks to all Orientations
    // Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();

    Orientation.addDeviceOrientationListener(handleChangeOrientation);

    return () => {
      Orientation.removeAllListeners(handleChangeOrientation);
      console.log('Bye see you soon ! ');
    };
  }, []);


  const handleChangeOrientation = orientation => {
    console.log(' Device orientation change to:', orientation);
    setDeviceOrientation(orientation);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text>{deviceOrientation}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default AppScreen;
```